# On iOS, what is actually happening when you pass a double to a method expecting a [single] floating point number as an argument?

Tags: objective-c, ios, llvm

Say I have an a function:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithFloat:(float)aFloat;
```

and I call that function with a double precision floating point value as follows:

```
[self doSomethingWithFloat:12.0];
```

Is a conversion done from 12.0 (double) to 12.0f (single) at compile-time or runtime, or neither?

Just for clarity: I'm not asking for the difference between single precision and double 
precision floating point numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ObjectiveC actually follows most of C conventions - so floats are promoted to double per the C spec when passed to a function. The ObjectiveC compiler turns all methods into functions eventually, so your double works.

That said its best to turn on compiler warnings and pass CGFloats or floats - it just lets you know when you are losing precision.

Comment: Good answer, but I didn't catch whether the conversion in this example  from double to float happens at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Run time. You said I have float, its a float - 32 bits. You might have a double truncated to a float, then passed as a double (ie float extended to doulbe) on the stack for the other software to chug on.